# Determine set of displayed items in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, lazy-loading

My question in its simplest form: Is it possible to determine the subset of items (or the indices of the corresponding items) currently being displayed in a JavaFX TableView?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to implement lazy loading. Therefore, I subclass ObservableList and implement the code that fetches new items from the database in the overriden `E get(int index)` (using prefetch/cache). However, the entity objects might be changed by the user and are therefore observed by the database backend. That's why I'd like to detach them as soon as they are not displayed any more.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VirtualFlow to get the indizes of the first and the last visible cell: [Scroll TableView via a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193840/scroll-tableview-via-a-button)

However, as I understood it, this is more a hack then a real part of the API. Also you might run into trouble if you have more tables around, it will be triggered each time a table changes.