# Scroll TableView via a Button

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, tableview

*Background*

Using JavaFX, I render a [`TableView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) and a [`Button`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) side by side.

The Table contains a number of entries which are more then the Table size. Hence TableView automatically shows a scrollbar for scrolling down.

*The Problem*

I want to scroll down the table by using the button. So pressing the button, scroll down the table by 5 entries. I found the [`scrollTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#scrollTo-int-) method, which would be sufficient for the task, but I need an index to scroll to. Which I do not have, as far as I understand there is no "getfirstvisibleindex" method (or something similar, you get the idea).

How can a determine the table row index to scroll to?

***Edit***

Thanks everyone for helping me out. For the sake of completeness I post "my" final solution as well, which is based/copied on the link provided below, [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356298/javafx-how-to-focus-and-select-to-the-next-cell-with-a-listview-when-scrolling/20434361#20434361) and [Link2](http://cdelunas.wordpress.com/tag/javafx/). The following method is implemented as part of an extented version of TableView and will be called by a button. (Side Node: I am not sure if the check for the end is reached cased is really necessary.)

```
public void scrollbartest(){
    TableViewSkin skin = (TableViewSkin) getSkin();
    VirtualFlow vf = null;
    ObservableList<Node> kids = skin.getChildren();
    if (kids != null && !kids.isEmpty())
        {
            vf = (VirtualFlow)kids.get(1);
        }
    if (vf == null) { return; }
    if (vf.getFirstVisibleCell() == null) { return; }

    int first = vf.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
    int last = vf.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex();

    int numberofrows = this.getItems().size();

    if(last != numberofrows-1){
        this.scrollTo(first+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get first and last visible cells with a little trick explained [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20434361/2855515)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the tableview tutorial as an example:  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

The TableView is backed by an observable list of some object type you define.  In the tutorial, they use:

```
    final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
    new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
    new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
    new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
    new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
    new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
);
```

Along with the line:

```
table.setItems(data);
```

The data list object has a size method which would be useful for your case.  In your button action, you could look up the size of the list and set the scrollTo() index 5 positions forward.  Just keep track of what the starting index is outside of the button action definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I keep track of the starting index? As far as I understood the Tableview loads the whole List and then renders it accordingly

Comment: Take a look at getSelectionModel() for a table.  When the table is initially rendered, no row is selected.  Calling table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() will return -1, meaning nothing is selected.  You could select the firs row by doing table.getSelectionModel().select(0) and then calling table.scrollTo(0).  For your button, replace 0 with some variable where you're tracking the offset.